# Array with a "graphical wrong" space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've started jQuery, html and css recently and I do not really understand everything. As the work deals with all of these things, I don't know where my problem comes from.

I want to generate a html array with js (data will come (later) from a server). This array might be "dynamic" (automatic filling, updating, etc.) and nice to see (hence css).

I do have something "good" right now. The only thing is I do have a "hidden" column and I can't get rid of it.

```js
var data = ["City 1", "City 2", "City 3"]; //headers

var data1= [["New York", 123, "Seattle"],
            ["Paris", "Milan", "Rome"],
            ["Pittsburg", "Wichita", "Boise"]];

var cityTable;


//Init and creation of the header
$(document).ready(function() {
  cityTable = makeTable($("#test"), data);
  appendTableColumn(cityTable, ["Calgary", "Ottawa", "Yellowknife"]);
});



// Add a line thanks to the button
$(function(){
        $('#button').click(
          function(e){
            appendTableColumn(cityTable, ["Calgary", "Ottawa", "Yellowknife"]);
          }
        )
    }
  )

//Add a line method
function appendTableColumn(table, rowData) {
    var lastRow = $("<tr class=\'row\'/>").appendTo(table.find('thead:last'));
    $.each(rowData, function(colIndex, c) {
        console.log(c);
        lastRow.append($('<td id="cell"  class=\'cell\'/>').text(c));
    });
    return lastRow;
}

//Creation of the table
function makeTable(container, data) {

    var table = $("<table/>");
    var row = $("<thead>");

    row.append($("<tr class=\'row\'/>"));
    $.each(data, function(rowIndex, r) {
      row.append($("<th>").text(r));
      row.append($("</th>"));
    });

    table.append(row);

    return container.append(table);
}
```

```css
tbody{
  display: : block;
  padding:20px;
  max-width:800px;
  margin:auto auto;
  font-family:sans;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table{

}


th {
  background:#666;
  color:#fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
td {
  padding:5px;
}

input {
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding:2px;
  border:0;
}
body {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}



.cell:hover{
background-color:#FF7368;
}
.row:hover{
  background-color:#E8CAB2;
}
.row:hover{
  background-color:#E8CAB2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Editable Table</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="in0.css">
  <link href="metro-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="in0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id='button' type="button" >Click Me!</button>
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Filter by Title">
  <table id="test"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, why you are creating table inside another table? 
Your '<th>' tags are added after <tr> instead of adding it inside 1st <tr>. Check if solving these issues can solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks. I tried but That s not fixing the issue. The first table is just for the display. It s "normal right now". This way I can print my table where I want on the page.
From another example, I fixed this issue adding the same css class every line but, here, it s not what I want.

Comment: There is no extra <td>(as you have mentioned in question) I can see while debugging your html code. May be this is some issue with your css.

Comment: Ok just to be sure, by (table using display) => using "div" ? I m also sure that the bug comes from the css, but where ? Thats the point. Because removing "class=\'row\'" solves the thing but I lose my underline. Otherwice, th elink doesn t work.

Comment: Yes using div you can create table. May be that will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don t really know why it s working but here what I changed and some words about.

```
function appendTableColumn(table, rowData) {
    var lastRow = $("<tr class=\'row\'>").appendTo(table.find('tbody:last'));
    $.each(rowData, function(colIndex, c) {
        console.log(c);
        lastRow.append($('<td id="cell"  class=\'cell\'/>').text(c));
    });
    return lastRow;
}

function makeTable(container, data) {

    var table = $("<table/>");
    var row = $("<thead class=\'row\'>");

    $.each(data, function(rowIndex, r) {
      row.append($("<th >").text(r));
      row.append($("</th>"));
    });

    table.append(row);
    var row1 = $("<tbody >");
    table.append(row1);
    return container.append(table);
}
```

The problem was to get ride of this "blanc". Hence I searched a way to add "class=\'row\'" to the head (That way it sovles the thing). Hence I created a tbdy part after my table decleration and closed the initial function.

In appendTable, I start from tbody and can file the array with th right css.

I can not say why it s working but the fact is it s good.

Thanks.